# sql server changes my where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

hello I'm trying to build a query with a where condition like this

> WHERE (dbo.Dosje.gjendja = 2) AND (dbo.Bashko.id IS NULL or dbo.Dosje.uniqueCode <> CONVERT(varchar(20), dbo.Dosje.qyteti + '_' + dbo.Bashko.kodiDytesor))

so is a condition like this A and (B or C) and it can normally transformed into 
(A and B) or (A and C)

but strange thing happens that sqlserver transform my where clause when i try to save or execute like this

> WHERE     (dbo.Dosje.gjendja = 2) AND (dbo.Bashko.id IS NULL) OR
>                         (dbo.Dosje.gjendja = 2) AND (dbo.Dosje.uniqueCode <> CONVERT(varchar(20), dbo.Dosje.qyteti + '_' + dbo.Bashko.kodiDytesor))

this is not the same logic. this is (A and B or A and C). that's not the same logic, why is sql server changing my query like this??

Comment: SQL Server *management studios view? designer* changes your SQL. If you stop using the view/query designer, bad things will stop happening. SQL Server itself isn't doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same logic. AND operator has higher priority than OR operator so it is always evaluated first. *A and B or A and C* is the same thing as *(A and B) or (A and C)*.